# ¿Colocar texto de celda de tabla html en forma vertical?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy buscando la forma de colocar el texto de una celda en forma vertical, hay un código `CSS` que uso el `transform` para hacer eso pero al usarlo lo que hace es rotar toda la celda y daña el diseño.

Lo que que quiero es lograr hacer esta tabla:

[image: Tabla]

pero con los textos que van en año (el 2017) y los meses que van en celdas combinadas de forma vertical.

Tengo este código, pero como les dije, mueve toda la celda y si, rota el texto pero daña el diseño completamente:

```css
.verticalText {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="div"><table border="1">
<tr id="Cabecera_1">
<th rowspan="2">Año</th>
<th rowspan="2">Mes</th>
<th rowspan="2">Día</th>
<th rowspan="2">Fecha</th>
<th rowspan="2">Añadir</th>
<th colspan="8">Horario</th>
</tr>
<tr id="Cabecera_2">
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Viernes_28">
<td rowspan="9" class="verticalText">2017</td>
<td rowspan="3" class="verticalText">Abril</td>
<td>Viernes</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Sabado_29">
<td>Sábado</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Domingo_30">
<td>Domingo</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<!-- Mayo -->
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Lunes_1">
<td rowspan="3" class="verticalText">Mayo</td>
<td>Lunes</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Martes_2">
<td>Martes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Miercoles_3">
<td>Miercoles</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</body>
```

También está el link de `jsfiddle.net` para que lo prueben:

https://jsfiddle.net/FabianMontoya97/r7tcgf7x/

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existe la propiedad CSS *writing-mode: vertical-lr;* la cual provee dicha funcionalidad. Acompañado de un *rotate* puede llegar a darle el diseño que tú esperas.

**NOTA:**
Observa que he agregado un tag **p** y a ese le he agregado tu clase, ya que el texto solo dentro de la celda no toma el efecto pues es requerido que el texto esté en una etiqueta especial de texto.

```css
.verticalText {
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="div"><table border="1">
<tr id="Cabecera_1">
<th rowspan="2">Año</th>
<th rowspan="2">Mes</th>
<th rowspan="2">Día</th>
<th rowspan="2">Fecha</th>
<th rowspan="2">Añadir</th>
<th colspan="8">Horario</th>
</tr>
<tr id="Cabecera_2">
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
<th>Inicial</th>
<th>Final</th>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Viernes_28">
<td rowspan="9"><p class="verticalText">2017</p></td>
<td rowspan="3"><p class="verticalText">Abril</p></td>
<td>Viernes</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Sabado_29">
<td>Sábado</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Abril_Domingo_30">
<td>Domingo</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<!-- Mayo -->
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Lunes_1">
<td rowspan="3"><p class="verticalText">Mayo</p></td>
<td>Lunes</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Martes_2">
<td>Martes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2017_Mayo_Miercoles_3">
<td>Miercoles</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>+</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Umm si, gracias, yo pensé lo mismo y lo intentaba usando algún `<b></b>` pero tampoco me funcionaba jaja, gracias, parece que está es la solución.

Comment: Hola lo que esta en forma vertical es la celda no el texto