# Texto vertical en un TD CSS no se ajusta a bordes

Tags: html, css

Necesito que el texto que tengo dentro de unos td aparezca de forma vertical de abajo a arriba, logre la dirección pero como el td tiene background color, se me sale de la linea borde que le puse al td...he encontrado funciones ya propias del css como:

```
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
```

Se ajustan al borde del td, pero la dirección de estos es de arriba a abajo y no al contrario como la necesito. Actualmente este es el css que falla al sobreponerse a las lineas de borde:

```
.verticaltext {
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);

}
```

Alguna idea ?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Colocar texto de celda de tabla html en forma vertical?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57837/colocar-texto-de-celda-de-tabla-html-en-forma-vertical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontre una forma, inicialmente la idea es que el background color lo tenga el tr y no el td, luego este seria el css que se ajusta adecuadamente quitando los wraps y poniendo padding:

```
.verticaltext {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: No te olvides de marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, para que la publicación se considere completa.